# How do I show which variables are not shared by two datasets in R?

Tags: r, compare

I have two data sets (A and B), one with 1600 observations/ rows and 1002 Variables/columns and one with 860 observations/rows and 1040 variables/ columns. I want to quickly check which variables are not contained in dataset A but are in dataset B and vice versa. I am only interestes in the column names, not in the onservations contained within these columns.
I found this great function here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arsenal/vignettes/comparedf.html and essencially I would want to get an output similar to this:
[image: Variables not shared output]
 The code I am trying is:
  `summary(comparedf(dataA, dataB))` 
 However, the table is not printed because R does a row by row comparision of both data sets and then runs out of space when printing the results in the console. Is there a quick way of achieving what I need here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `anti_join()` function from the `dplyr` package to find the unmatched records. It will give you an output of the rows that both data sets A and B do not share in common. Here is an example:-

```
table1<-data.frame(id=c(1:5), animal=c("cat", "dog", "parakeet", 
                                       "lion", "duck"))

table2<-table1[c(1,3,5),]

library(dplyr)
anti_join(table1, table2, by="id")

  id animal
1  2    dog
2  4   lion
```

This will return the unshared rows by ID.

***Edit***

If you are wanting to find which column names/variables appear in one data frame but not the other, then you could use this solution:-

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), not=rnorm(100))
df2 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100))

df1[, !names(df1) %in% names(df2)] #returns column/variable that appears in df1 but not in df2
```

I hope this answers your question. It will return the actual values beneath each unshared column/variable, but you could save the output to an object and run `colnames()` on it, which should print your unshared column/variable names.

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you for taking the time. The datasets partially share the same variable names but the observations are independent, thus there is no common denominator like an ID to pair by.

Comment: Furthermore, I am not looking for the difference in rows but for the difference in columns.

Comment: The difference in column names between the two dataframes? I think I have a solution, I will amend my answer

Comment: Nice, Robin. This also works wonderfully! Thank you.

Comment: @Anca no problem, happy to help! If you wouldn't mind upvoting on my solution that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit clunky, but combining `setdiff()` with `colnames()` may work.
Doing both `setdiff(colnames(DataA),colnames(DataB))` and `setdiff(colnames(DataB),colnames(DataA))` will give you 2 vectors, each with the names of the columns present in one of the datasets but not in the other one.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. You save me a couple of hours of work there, Antón.

Answer (score 0):

I always use an outersect function I copied from Tony Breyal at R-bloggers: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/11/outersect-the-opposite-of-rs-intersect-function/

```
outersect <- function(x, y) {
  sort(c(setdiff(x, y),
         setdiff(y, x)))
}
```

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)